# Rails Processing by SessionsController#create as */*

Tags: controller

I have created a form in C# and post it to my rails server, and from console it respond to me that `Processing by SessionsController#create as */*`

How can I make it process as HTML? I've googled and seems there is a `respond_to` function I can use, and I have added it to my `def create` in Sessions like below:

```
def create
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
   end
end
```

But then when I re-run, it still shows `Processing by SessionsController#create as */*`
Where have I went wrong? Thanks!